# Conical intersection using GAMESS

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry

I would like to know how to locate conical intersection using a GAMESS calculation. I really appreciate an example alone with this since I am a novice I do not have a clear idea among bunch of examples on internet given. Also I want to know the parameters as well especially for the $DATA part in GAMESS.

Comment: Setting up the CAS for a specific system is already a complex task; there is no general recipe for that. What you are asking goes beyond that. You are not even specifying a system that you want to calculate. I'm afraid this questions is too broad to be answerable.

Comment: Since I am a novice I have this problem. I am working on a photochromic compound. I need to locate the conical intersection to find the transition state. I have GAMESS software to do it.  I could not write the proper input so far. I will send more information